# How to put the Apache POI generated files directly into the database Please

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-poi

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
byte[] BinaryFileBytes = wb.getBytes();
```

Use this code,I can get a byte array object and write it to database.
But I can't export it.Whether to generate to local import database? Please.

Comment: store the files in database in the column having datatype as blob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not writing the file out correctly. From [the getBytes() javadocs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#getBytes%28%29):

> Method getBytes - get the bytes of just the HSSF portions of the XLS file. Use this to construct a POI POIFSFileSystem yourself.

If you want to get the bytes of the whole file, you should instead do something like:

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
// Populate

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
wb.write(baos);
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
```

Alternately, see if your database provides an OutputStream for writing data to a blob store, and if so just pass that to the `wb.write(out)` call directly